# How to use GWT color picker

Tags: gwt, color-picker

I found gwt example for color picker. For example here is one link : http://www.subshell.com/en/subshell/blog/Implementing-a-Color-Picker-Dialog-With-Canvas-and-GWT100.html. But I want color picker something like below image :

[image]

How to develop this type of color picker in GWT. In GWT is tit possible to develop this type of color picker? Or is there any better way to develop this type of color picker?

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You already have half of the solution as per the shared link. Think of your custom color picker as a panel consisting of 2X2 grid and a button panel in bottom. Your 2X2 grid contains 4 panels:

1. Basic colors: Buttons of fixed colors
2. Subshell color picker
3. Custom colors: Button of custom colors
4. Add to custom colors: Input fields to take RGB & other values

Answer (score 0):

Can you integrate some javascript and HTML5 in this? If you can this tutorial was amazing for me to develop my website's one by using the canevas. Check it out

http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2013/03/how-to-create-a-color-picker-with-html5-canvas/